# How to test Creating and Cancelling Subscription in ThriveCart in Test Mode

Tags: laravel, testing, payment, checkout, subscription

I am integrating ThriveCart Checkout For payment in my laravel project.
I implemented Creating and Cancelling subscription and I want to do some test.

I think creating subscription seems to succeed.
When I click on 'Select this plan' on my web page

[image]

it redirects to ThriveCart checkout page and if I confirm the details of payment, I got success in my webhook and also can confirm the purchase in ThriveCart Dashboard.

But when I try to cancel this subscription by using the following code

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$cancel_url = 'https://thrivecart.com/api/external/cancelSubscription?passthrough[type]=cancel';

try{
    Log::info("Canceling subscription plan");

    $res = $client->request(
        'POST',
        $cancel_url,
        [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $api_key,
                'X-TC-Mode' => $api_mode,
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'order_id' => $thrivecart_order_id,
                'subscription_id' => $thrivecart_subscription_id
            ]
        ]
    );
```

I get the following error

```json
"error": "You must provide matching customer IDs."
```

I think in test mode, the subscription isn't created but not sure.
Can anyone explain how to test Subscription in ThriveCart?

Comment: Can you share the URL to the documentation when it talks about what you are doing?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Here is the link of api documentation and usage
https://apidocs.thrivecart.com/#5b48d95b-703f-4390-bc9a-43d845e31cd4
https://developers.thrivecart.com/documentation/

Comment: I am assuming that the connected order or subscription ID is not related to a customer (I have never used their API)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @matiaslauriti,
I am testing with the well known test card - 4242424242424242 and after I confirm checkout, i get notification in my webhook and through the payload, I get the subscriptionID and orderID and also customerID, But cancelling api doesn't require customerID, just need the thriveCart owner's secret key and access token